# How to recreate the image using HTML and CSS?

Tags: css, transparency

How to recreate the image mock-up using HTML and CSS?

How do I achieve that curve at the end of the rctangular div?

How will I insert a small transparent region between the rectangular div and the circular div, where the transparent gap should inherit any color/ image from the outer wrapper div, and not from the rectangle div, over which the circular div is placed?

I tried placing a transparent circle outside the circular div, but that will not inherit the color from the outer wrapper, but it will inherit the color of the rectangular div, if its background color is set to *transparent*.
[image]

**EDIT**: To reduce any sort of confusion, use this as a reference. This is what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
}
.rectangle{
  width: 70%;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.circle{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid;
  top: -5px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you be fine with using a SVG?

Answer (score 2):

You can play with the `radial gradient` to try and make a shape at the end of the rectangle to match your needs.

This is my effort as an example:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 10%;
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.rectangle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 100px;
  top: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 100% calc(100% + 35px), rgba(0,0,0,0) 110px, #000000 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

[More information about radial gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient)

Comment: This is actually a very sneaky solution. Sneaky, sneaky ! But it works, +1 to your credit.

Answer (score -1):

> How will I insert a small transparent region between the rectangular div and the circular div, where the transparent gap should inherit any color/ image from the outer wrapper div, and not from the rectangle div, over which the circular div is placed?

You can set some color on the `.wrapper` and use it in a descendant as a background color with keyword **`currentColor`**
If you truly want some transparent area, you should not paint anything in that area in the first place. Easier to do in SVG if the shape is too complex for CSS.

[MDN on currentColor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#currentColor_keyword)
[A few use cases](https://osvaldas.info/keeping-css-short-with-currentcolor) (beware of IE with linear-gradient :( )

Note: `z-index: 1` is fine. No reason for 999 or 1000000§§§ except if you asked for it with 998 :o

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  color: white; /* reference */
}
.rectangle{
  width: 70%;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.circle{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid currentColor; /* used here */
  top: -5px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But what if the background of the outermost div has a background-image, and not a background-color? Or say, it has a gradient background?